# Trim JavaScript object to specified properties with matching values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to verify that an object has a certain set of properties and that their values are of a certain type. I'd like to be able to compare an object to a template like

```
name: "string",
age: "number",
registered: "boolean"
```

and return an object with only the fields that match the template.

```
var object = {
    name: "John McClane",
    age: 45,
    location: "Nakatomi Towers",
    registered: "yes"
}

var document = match(object, template);
console.log(document); 

/* Should return 
{
    name: "John McClane",
    age: 45
}
*/
```

What are the JavaScript best practices in writing a function like this? I'm not too familiar with the built in methods and iteration so I don't want to go about this the wrong way.

Comment: There are no specific 'best practices' for this. If writing this, using `in` and `typeof` would probably be helpful starts - ignoring edge cases. There is no built-in feature for such a test. There are probably existing 3rd party libraries (FSVO) under the guise of 'JSON schema validation' or similar.

Comment: Are you okay with using a library like Underscore or LoDash? Or do you want to stick to plain JavaScript?

Comment: Programmers.SE is for whiteboarding design problems.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y9s9xsbv/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to produce an array of `template` keys, [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over those keys and create a single result object, [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to test if `object` has that key and `typeof` to test the type of `object[key]`.

```
function match(obj, tpl) {
    return Object.keys(tpl).reduce(function(collection, key) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof obj[key] === tpl[key]) {
            collection[key] = obj[key];
        }
        return collection;
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `typeof` might not work for **all** cases, for instance `null`. [Something like this](https://goo.gl/pxwQGp) should probably be the type matching function

Comment: @nem true. If OP wants to test for types like `Array`, `typeof` isn't going to cut it either but given the sample of `"string"`, `"number"` and `"boolean"`, it should suffice